# Get Dynamic Edit Text with List View (Android) like Whatsapp, Messenger

Tags: java, android, xml

**I want a Dynamic Edit Text, in which I put whatever I want and after Click on  SEND button, it should display in same List View Activity.[image]**

[image]

Comment: for start, put LinearLayout on top of the edit box, and whenever you click the send button, read the text from the edit text view and dynamically add new view to Linear Layout

Comment: `LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.chatwindow);
...
linearLayout.addView(chatmessage);`